# Como instanciar uma classe abstract no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, winforms, classes-abstratas

Sei que a classe `abstract` não pode ser instanciada. Mas preciso chamá-la no Windows Forms e não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Antes de postar algo faça o Tour https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour do site para saber como fazer as perguntas. Quando tiver problemas com código diga-nos o que já tentou fazer e quais os erros que esta a obter.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque o seu código e/ou o que já fez até o momento.. Juntamente com isso, explique o que está tentando fazer (o problema por completo).

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível, o motivo dela ser abstrata é justamente não permitir que seja instanciada. Este tipo de classe existe para ser herdada.

Você pode herdá-la em uma classe concreta e instanciar esta classe filha. É provável que precise implementar alguma parte faltante.

Talvez não seja o certo a fazer. Se precisa de uma classe abstrata do jeito que ela foi concebida fica estranho. O problema pode ser outro.

Comment: Então como eu faria?

Comment: Você leu a resposta?

Comment: Sim, sou iniciante no C#.